# .htaccess rewrites not being read

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following in htaccess:

```
  RewriteEngine on          
  RewriteRule ^list/([A-Za-z0-9_\.-]+).html?$ list.php?table=$1 [QSA,L]
```

In virtualhosts:
            
                ServerName localhost
                DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
                
                    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                    AllowOverride All
                    Order allow,deny
                    allow from all

```
        <VirtualHost *:80>    
            DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/kurz/site/www"
            ServerName kurz.local
            <Directory c:/wamp/www/kurz/site/www>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
            </Directory>
        </VirtualHost>
```

in apache config:

```
        DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"
        <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order deny,allow
            Deny from all
        </Directory>
```

Now the weird problem is:
there is a rewrite happening, even AFTER i delete the .htaccess, I tried also removing ALL other sites in the www folder, but there's still a  rewrite happening from somewhere (do these things cache? i tried clearing browser cache and all that),

BUT

if I put some jibberish in the .htaccess, i get a server error, so I know it is being read!

the other problem is that the rewrite is not passing any variables,
this link works:

http://kurz.local/admin/list/pages.html

but it seems to take to:

http://kurz.local/admin/list.php

instead of

http://kurz.local/admin/list.php?table=pages

online this setup is working, but locally it's not

any ideas ?
i'm really puzzled!

Comment: What do you mean `...this link works: http://kurz.local/admin/list/pages.html`, for example? ¿Why it works? Give more information, explain in detail what you want redirected and how, with examples. Trying to guess what you need from a rewrite rule that doesn't work, it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned if you restarted the server?  editing server config files needs a restart, but I believe .htaccess file changes do not need apache server restart.

Comment: yes, I did restart the server after every change .. I wish that was the problem! :(

Answer (score 0):

Your server doc root is:
c:/wamp/www/

Your virtual host doc root is inside the above, I don't think that is allowed.

It should be :

c:/wamp/vhosts/site1root

c:/wamp/vhosts/site2root

etc.

Also see this: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html